# Why doesn't gnosis safe bubble error messages instead of generic gs013 error

Tags: gnosis-safe

One annoying thing about working with gnosis safes is the generic "GS013" error code when the transaction from the gnosis safe fails; it makes it difficult to debug why the underlying transaction failed. Why doesn't the contract bubble up the underlying error in the contract call to make issues easier to debug? The `call` and `delegateCall` in [execute](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/Executor.sol) should also return a return value that includes the error message with why the underlying transaction failed.

Answer (score 1):

It was done primarily for gas optimization. It's not worth putting the logic into the contract to be executed on-chain when you can run it off-chain where it's cheaper.

Debugging the transaction is relatively easy with Tenderly, you just need to input the transaction hash or simulate the transaction.

You can also use [SimulateTxAcessor](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/accessors/SimulateTxAccessor.sol) to simulate the transaction, this method always reverts and returns data in `success:bool || response.length:uint256 || response:bytes` format and you can decode the error from the response.

Comment: I was wondering this same thing a while ago. While this makes sense, it would _also_ make sense to include a message to devs in the GS013 error that this could be (/likely is?) masking other errors that can be discovered by simulating on tenderly. Even better: generate a tenderly link that will run that simulation for the user to click on.